# OAuth 2.0 Code Grant flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

There is a [sample implementation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) of the OAuth 2.0 Authorization server and sample workflow for each grant type.

The IETF has an OAuth 2.0 specification for the [Code Grant Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).
When you take a look at the steps "D" & "E" in the chart of the IETF Code Grant Flow, they don't seemt to be implemented in the sample implementation(first link).

Where are the steps D & E in the sample implementation?
I know that it is a sample implementation which is not production ready, but I assumed that it will follow the specs for OAuth 2.0.

In the sample application the client gets the code, but does not forward it to the OAuth server to obtain the tokens.
Actually it gets the tokens including code already in step 3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I downloaded the Microsoft.Owin sources and debugged through the code.

The DotnetOAuth client libs send a token request under the hood.
I couldn't see it when using Fiddler, because it uses a WebRequest object and therefore gets not captured by Fidddler ootb!

The token request contains the code token and it also gets validated

It will be validated in the

> ReceiveAuthenticationToken
>   eventhandler.

The code token is created here:

```
private void CreateAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext ctx)
{
    var code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
    ctx.SetToken(code);
    _authenticationCodes[ctx.Token] = ctx.SerializeTicket(); <-- stored in a concurrentDictionary as the key for the auth ticket, for demonstration purposes only
// delete the entry, must only be used once
}
```